# Perl: select encoding based on the environment

Tags: perl, internationalization

I'm attempting to discern the proper perl encoding to use based on the language set in the environment.  This works well when the language is a UTF-8 language, but one user has tried to set their LANG to "Ja_JP" on AIX.

```
$ LANG=Ja_JP perl -MI18N::Langinfo=langinfo,CODESET -E 'say langinfo(CODESET)'
IBM-943
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert this into something that binmode will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page on [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS),

> IBM CCSID 943 has the same extensions as Code Page 932.

So you could use `:encoding(cp932)`

---

To make `:encoding(IBM-943)` work, you need to create an alias in Encode::Alias.

You could file a feature request to have this alias added, or you could define it yourself in your script:

```
use Encode::Alias qw( define_alias );
define_alias( qr/^ibm-943$/i => '"cp932"' );
```

You'll need the place the `define_alias` call inside a `BEGIN { }` if you're going to follow with

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
```

Comment: cp932 (and thus IBM-943) differs from Shift JIS in that `5C` is "`\ `" (like in ASCII) instead of "`¥`". The character set wouldn't otherwise include the Windows directory separator. Fonts used in conjunction with cp932 sometimes display `\ ` as `¥`.

Comment: So it's something that each perl dev has to catch and handle, then. I was hoping that was already encapsulated somewhere, but maybe it's just AIX that isn't being handled because it's not one of the normal platforms being targeted.  Thanks, @ikegami .

Comment: It is encapsulated somewhere. Devs do not need to catch and handle it.  For example, `:encoding(latin1)` works because `latin1` is defined in Encode::Alias as an alias for `iso-8859-1`. It's just that your particular alias isn't defined in Encode::Alias. So again, what you need to do is file a feature request to have this alias added to Encode::Alias.

Comment: ... Once it's there, you just need the statement at the bottom of my answer.